# Will my existing Approved App get removed from AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

What will happen to my existing approved APPS, if I do not renew my paid IOS Developer Program(From Apple).

I know that I will not be able to submit new Apps with this Account and not able to update my existing apps, I am seriously very confused about this.

Comment: almost sure it will be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't renew your paid developer program, your apps will no longer be available for download on the App Store. However if you start paying again your account can be restored as it was before. This happened to a customer to our company once.

Here is Apple's info on what will happen if you don't pay:

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html

Answer (score 2):

> If I don't renew my membership, will new customers be able to purchase
>   my app from the App Store?
>
> No. Once your membership expires, your app will be removed from the
>   App Store and new customers will no longer be able to purchase your
>   app.

havent experienced myself but I wouldnt take the chance. pay the $99

[apple developer program renewals](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html)

Comment: I've encountered it, my app was unavailable until I renewed my developer membership (and then I got an email from iTunes Connect saying that my app was available again).